# How do I check for a script in the header using Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have the following JS file in the dom...

```
<head>
    ...
    <script async="" src="https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-2412019.js?sv=6"></script>
</head>
```

I am trying to write a test to check this...

```
cy.get("script").should("have.attr", "src").should("include", "hotjar");
```

But I get...

```
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '[ <script>, 3 more... ]' to have attribute 'src'
```

Comment: How many script tags do you have inside your head tag?

Answer (score 1):

> expected '[ , 3 more... ]' to have attribute 'src'

means at least one of those doesn't have a src attribute.

You can incorporate the `src` attribute check in the selector

```
  cy.get('head script[src*="hotjar"]')  // fails if no hotjar script present
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cy.document() //Important, because Cypress has its own Head
    .get('head script')
    .should("have.attr", "src")
    .should("include", "hotjar");
```

Or

```
cy.get('head')
    .then(head => {
        let headToText = JSON.stringify(head.html())
        expect(headToText).to.contain(scriptText)
    })
```